# Azure B2C Customization - Change “Sign in with your Social Account” text

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I will like to be able to change the following texts on a B2C signin signup page.

1. “Sign in with your social account”
2. “Sign in with your existing account”

I am not a content developer. I have a html page That references some css and then the  element. But I have not been able to modify the texts above since it comes from B2C.

Is it possible? How do I go about it? Also if I switched to a Sign in policy, what are the limitations with customizations?

Answer (score 4):

```
<LocalizedResources Id="api.signuporsignin.en">
<LocalizedStrings>
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="social_intro">#Sign in with your social account</LocalizedString>
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="local_intro_email">#Sign in with your existing account</LocalizedString>
</LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>

<ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
<LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
    <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.en" />
</LocalizedResourcesReferences>
```

Refer this link for the complete customization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-localization

Comment: Thanks @Rohit! Will give this a shot

Answer (score 2):

If you have created a built-in flow, then you can customize the page strings, as described at [Language customization in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-language-customization).

E.g. You can customize the page string for the sign-in text:

```
{
  "ElementType": "UxElement",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "social_intro",
  "Override": false,
  "Value": "Sign in with your social account"
}
```

with:

```
{
  "ElementType": "UxElement",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "social_intro",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Log in with an external account"
}
```